# Por que fracionar um insert melhora sua performance?

Tags: sql, desempenho

Supondo que eu tenha uma tabela `order_items` que registra os itens de um pedido, e neste exemplo, o usuário estaria fazendo 1 pedido de 10.000 computadores. No momento de registrar os itens do pedido no banco dados, gostaria de entender porque ambas as operações de `insert`:

```sql
insert into order_items (user_id, order_id, name, price) values (1, 1, 'Computer', 3.400)
insert into order_items (user_id, order_id, name, price) values (1, 1, 'Computer', 3.400)
insert into order_items (user_id, order_id, name, price) values (1, 1, 'Computer', 3.400)
insert into order_items (user_id, order_id, name, price) values (1, 1, 'Computer', 3.400)
outros 10.000 inserts
```

```sql
insert into order_items (user_id, order_id, name, price) values (1, 1, 'Computer', 3.400),
                                                                (1, 1, 'Computer', 3.400),
                                                                (1, 1, 'Computer', 3.400),
                                                                (1, 1, 'Computer', 3.400),
                                                                +10.000 registros
```

Apresentam uma performance muito inferior em relação ao modelo abaixo?:

```sql
insert into order_items (user_id, order_id, name, price) values (1, 1, 'Computer', 3.400),
                                                                (1, 1, 'Computer', 3.400),
                                                                (1, 1, 'Computer', 3.400),
                                                                (1, 1, 'Computer', 3.400),
                                                                +2497 registros
insert into order_items (user_id, order_id, name, price) values (1, 1, 'Computer', 3.400),
                                                                (1, 1, 'Computer', 3.400),
                                                                (1, 1, 'Computer', 3.400),
                                                                (1, 1, 'Computer', 3.400),
                                                                +2497 registros
insert into order_items (user_id, order_id, name, price) values (1, 1, 'Computer', 3.400),
                                                                (1, 1, 'Computer', 3.400),
                                                                (1, 1, 'Computer', 3.400),
                                                                (1, 1, 'Computer', 3.400),
                                                                +2497 registros
insert into order_items (user_id, order_id, name, price) values (1, 1, 'Computer', 3.400),
                                                                (1, 1, 'Computer', 3.400),
                                                                (1, 1, 'Computer', 3.400),
                                                                (1, 1, 'Computer', 3.400),
                                                                +2497 registros
```

Resultados obtidos em teste com um banco `MySQL`:

Para o 1º exemplo `1.04 sec`

Para o 2º exemplo `0.234 sec`

Para o 3º exemplo `0.094 sec`

A impressão que tive é que a diferença de tempo fica mais clara quando se tem mais registros sendo inseridos, mas é apenas uma impressão mesmo

Comment: Seria interessante juntar a pergunta os dados de análise das consultas em questão.

Comment: *"Apresentam uma performance muito inferio"* e como chegou a essa conclusão? pode adicionar esses dados na pergunta? E pf também informe o banco de dados, isso faz **toda a diferença nas respostas**. De qualquer forma, é muito mais performática fazer uma única operação, pq se valida e transaciona de uma vez, mas, dependendo do banco, isso envolve gravar log para fazer rollback, atualizar índices, etc, por isso precisa ver o plano de execução e entender melhor.

Comment: Se a opção AUTOCOMMIT estiver ligada então os procedimentos referentes ao COMMIT serão realizados a cada comando. Tais procedimentos tem custo alto e por isso quando você coloca diversas tuplas a cada INSERT tem uma performance melhor. Avalie definir uma única transação `BEGIN` (lista dos comandos INSERT) `COMMIT` e observe o tempo de execução.

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta com o banco utilizado e o tempo que levou para a execução de cada operação. Como disse ali, a impressão que **eu** tive é que essa diferença no tempo parece mais clara quando você está fazendo a inserção de uma quantidade maior de registros.

Answer (score 0):

Isso pode ser muito relativo. Pode depender da configuração e estrutura do próprio banco. No Sql Server normalmente isso pode estar relacionado com o fato de o banco precisar reservar recursos para a estrutura de log e transação. Fazendo com que o SGBD sofra uma certa lentidão enquanto todos os inserts estão sendo processados em uma mesma transação e o banco ainda não realizou o commit para liberar estes recursos que consomem memória e processamento.

Mas, para uma análise mais exata é preciso verificar o plano de execução.